# Sendgrid timezone

Tags: date, timestamp, sendgrid

I'm sending emails using the Sendgrid API, & I wanna use the `"send_at"` where I must convert the date to timestamp first..
Well, what timezone shall I use? & is there any other way avoiding the convertion to timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sendgrid API has the send_at parameter which is a **UNIX timestamp** format.

Here is an example for using the send_at email header:

```
{
  "send_at": 1409348513
}
```

To schedule a send request for a large batch of emails use the send_at parameter which will send all emails at approximately the same time.

**Timezone** issues with scheduling emails, please remember that you have the option to specify a timezone when you schedule the email to go out.
If you don’t specify the timezone, it will default to current Pacific Time (UTC-7 or UTC-8, depending on your daylight savings time).

In order to specify the timezone assigned to the user you can call the following API:

```
Post Url: 
https://api.sendgrid.com/api/timezone/edit.json

Post Data:  api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&timezone=America/New_York
```

The following API updates the timezone assigned to the user.

Comment: How can I specify the timezone?